# Pattern match using regex in C

Tags: c, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to match an user input with a certain predefined patterns. Here is the situation:

Lets say the user enters: `@myFrined messageToSend`, it should match: `@[:word:] [:word:]`.

What I tried for now:

```
//get line from stdin
size_t len = 0;
size_t input_size;
char *command = NULL;

input_size = getline(&command, &len, stdin);

printf("Read %lu characters\n", input_size);
printf("Input: %s", command);

regex_t regex;

//predefine patterns
char* exit_command = "/exit";
char* login_command = "/login [:word:] [:word:]";
char* privmsg_command = "@[:word:] [:word:]";
char* register_command = "/register [:word:] [:word:]";

//pattern results: 0 match ||| 1 not a match
int pattern_command_exit;
int pattern_command_login;
int pattern_command_privmsg;
int pattern_command_register;

//test the input against the patters
pattern_command_exit = regcomp(&regex, exit_command, 0);
pattern_command_exit = regexec(&regex, command, 0, NULL, 0);

pattern_command_login = regcomp(&regex, login_command, 0);
pattern_command_login = regexec(&regex, command, 0, NULL, 0);

pattern_command_privmsg = regcomp(&regex, privmsg_command, 0);
pattern_command_privmsg = regexec(&regex, command, 0, NULL, 0);

pattern_command_register = regcomp(&regex, register_command, 0);
pattern_command_register = regexec(&regex, command, 0, NULL, 0);

//*******actual results*******// 
printf("/exit: %d\n", pattern_command_exit);
printf("/login: %d\n", pattern_command_login);
printf("/private message: %d\n", pattern_command_privmsg);
printf("/register: %d\n", pattern_command_register);
```

This is working only for `/exit`, which makes sense since I did something wrong somewhere.

Any ideas how I can correctly use regexes to match these patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems:

1. The character class name needs to be enclosed in two brackets on each side, e.g. `[[:alpha:]]`.
2. Even if the syntax was correct, `word` is not a valid character class, the only valid character classes are (from [the manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html)):

   ```
   alnum   digit   punct
   alpha   graph   space
   blank   lower   upper
   cntrl   print   xdigit
   ```
3. If you want to match multiple characters of the same class, you also need a `\+` (which escaped becomes `\\+`), e.g. `"[[:alnum:]]\\+"`.

You will have to either choose one from those, or if none suits your needs just use a custom bracket expression, like for example `[a-zA-z0-9_-]\\+` to match one or more alphanumeric characters (upper or lower) plus `-` and `_`.

Comment: Also the character class needs to be inside two sets of brackets - `[[:alpha:]]`, where OP is only using one.

Comment: ok I see your point. No I change it to `char* login_command = "/login [[:alpha:]] [[:alpha:]]"` and the expression matches a single char from the word "alpha" so valid will be: `/login a a` or `/login l a` but not `/login zzzz zzzzz`. Maybe I am just stupid :)

Comment: @JohnRambo right, updated my answer, totally missed that.